# formatting header row of a CSV with ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I work with a lot of CSV files that have UTF-8 characters in them - namely Chinese traditional. There is one particular situation I came across today where the header row of my CSV file was so garbled that I needed to replace it (I have the exact values to do so). The rest of the CSV data was actually fine.

What I am trying to work out is how can I (using ruby) simply open the CSV file in question, delete the existing header row and then replace it with the correct header row without having to load the entire file. If I could do this instead of having to deal with badly formatted headers it would save me some serious time!

Comment: We need to see your effort. It's a lot easier for us to correct your code than for us to write something with no knowledge of what you've done, and then you try to shoehorn it into place.

Comment: As far as I know, in CSV partial write is not possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV files are not made up of fixed-length records, instead they're usually a file consisting of variable length-strings. As a result, you can't delete or insert a line without reading the entire file.

You *can* change the line as long as the changed content is exactly the same size, in bytes, as the old text, however that's very unlikely.

Instead I'd do something like this:

1. Open a new file in `"w"` mode.
2. Write the new header to it.
3. Open the old (CSV) file as if it's a text file using `"r"` mode.
4. Read a line.
5. Use `$.` to see if you're on the first line. If so, skip to the end of your loop.
6. If `$.` is greater than the first line, write the line.
7. loop to #4.
8. Close the input file.
9. Close the output file.

Here's the same idea implemented, but not tested, in Ruby:

```
NEW_HEADER = 'some, csv, header'

File.open('new_csv_file', 'w') do |fo|
  File.foreach('old_csv_file') do |li|
    if $. > 1
      fo.puts li
    else
      fo.puts NEW_HEADER
    end
  end
end
```

Like I said, it's not tested, but that should get you started.

---

> what does $. do?

To quote "The Ruby Programming Language" about `$.`:

> The number of the last line read from the current input file. Equivalent to `ARGF.lineno`. English synonyms: `$NR`, `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER`.

It's a Perl-ism, which might have inherited it from shell, if I remember right.

Comment: oh I see, let me test this and see how it goes. I did have one question on your answer - what does $. do?

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the info! this is basically exactly what I was looking for!